# Compilation of a book takes a lot of time

Tags: polyglossia, import

I'm finalizing a probability book, in an english version. I give its general architecture, in the file `Main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\usepackage{ProbaModBE}

\includeonly{Stat-Data}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{FrontBook}

\mainmatter
\include{Stat-Data}
\include{Stat-Param}
\include{Rand-Calc}
\include{Proba-Space}
\include{Rand-Var}
\include{Usual-Rand-Var}

\begin{appendices}
\include{Appendix-Quantiles-Functions}
\include{Appendix-Moments-Inequalities}
\end{appendices}

\stopcontents[chapter]

\backmatter
\include{Index}
\include{Glossary-Equations}
\include{Glossary-Authors}
\include{Dictionnaries}
\include{Normal-Tables}

\end{document}
```

The different includes are chapter of the books in the main part, or annexes in the backmatter part.

The package `ProbaModBE.sty` is my own personal package, containing several commands and packages, particularly the following language commands:

```
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setmainfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,ItalicFont={Amiri},Scale=1.3]{Traditional Arabic}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
%%%\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
```

I use the `polyglossia` package, for the languages, and Arabic language to include some footnotes comments in Arabic, and a dictionary in appendices, grouping these footnotes. The file compiles well, and I used it several times, for producing many textbooks for example...

From some times, the compilation of my documents take much more time than usual, and I don't know why... I suspect the moment when I started the use of the commands `\subimport` in my files where I use the command `\import`...

**Update**
I explain how I use the package `import`: The book folder contains two subfolders, "Main_files" and "Chapters_files". The folder "Main files" contains the file "Main.tex" and the include files. The "Chapters files" contains folders of each chapter. Say for example, the folder "Stat-Data" for the first chapter, which contains two files, "Stat-Data-Cours.tex" and "Stat-Data-Exos.tex", and the sub-folder `Exos`, where I put the exercises of the chapter "Stat-Data". Now, in the folder "Main files", one include is the file of the first chapter `Stat-Data.tex`, which contains the commands `\import{..\Chapters_files\Stat-Data-Cours.tex} \import{..\Chapters_files\Stat-Data-Exos.tex}`. Finally the file "Stat-Data-Exos.tex" contains the commands `\subimport{..\Exos\Exo1.tex} \subimport{..\Exos\Exo2.tex}....` for the different exercises... I hope it's clear and I apologize for taking your attention.

I give an indication of the time spent: I compile only the first chapter, with the command `\includeonly{Stat-Data}`, and I follow the compilation with the TeXworks software. The end of compilation takes a lot of time, and I don't know the signification of it ! This end is synthesized in the "output console" of TeXworks by the list:

```
(Main.aux (FrontBook.aux) (Stat-Data.aux) (Stat-Param.aux) (Rand-Calc.aux)
(Proba-Space.aux) (Rand-Var.aux) (Usual-Rand-Var.aux)
(Appendix-Quantiles-Functions.aux) (Appendix-Moments-Inequalities.aux)
(Index.aux) (Glossary-Equations.aux) (Glossary-Authors.aux) (Dictionnaries.aux)
 (Normal-Tables.aux))
```

Every appearance of an `.aux` file takes a lot of time... Between the beginning of the list of .aux files, by `Main.aux`,  and its end by the command `Transcript written on Main.log.`, we spent `2'20` seconds, which is really abnormal !!

I don't know what do exactly the compiler in this end phase, but I suppose that it writes (where ?) some information of each `.aux` file. We can find each file of the `.aux` list in the `.log` file... which contains 48950 lines !!. I give an example:

```
 (Stat-Data.aux
\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 17.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 17.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 17.
```

... (here. this watches that I use the package morewrites)... and after, the same message `on input line 25` for the 3 families, after `on input line 28`... for one thousand lines, till the commands:

```
 (Stat-Param.aux
\openout6 = `Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.
....
....
```

.... and same things for other thousands of lines, for each .aux file !

Does someone can explain me  what do exactly the compiler in this end phase, what's the signification of these messages, `Redefining \rmfamily`, `Redefining \sffamily`, `Redefining \ttfamily`, and give me a way to optimize my files, especially these commands for fonts, for a precious gain of time... 
What's the correlation of all this with my first suspect, the `\import` and `\subimport`, commands !?

**Update**
I put the table of contents and the list of figures of the book, for an idea of the material used. The files in the backmatter are made using the `glossaries` package.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You do not say how long the book is and what it contains. If, for example, you have lots of mages or plots, or the book runs to thousands of pages etc then it will take a long time to compile. Without seeing your actual content is is really hard to say. You could try using the [subfiles](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package if you want to be able to compile individual parts of the book. The font definitions just mean that you are not using the standard fonts. This won't cost anything in time, except possibly the first compilation.

Comment: Here I compile only one chapter. I'll try to publish the table of contents and the list of figures. Thanks

Comment: But those repeated lines of the log file seem really strange.  Redefining `\??family` three times every few lines, `\openout6 = 'Main.mw.mw.mw.mw.mw'.` for thousands of lines.  Are there other commands in `ProbaModBE.sty` that relate to writing files (or the `\??family` commands)?  You suspected `\(sub)import`, but you haven't shown us how you use that.

Comment: Import could potentially be causing the problem, so put together a proper minimal but complete demonstration. My suspicion is that something else is broken, but "import" slows down the (multiple) file searches enough that you noticed a difference. Also, make sure you have the latest import.sty (it was updated recently [in 2020]).

Comment: Morewrites can slow down a lot!

Comment: I update my post, where I make some explaination of how I use (sub)import, and put (a draft) of table of contents and list of figures, for an idea

Comment: @Teepeemm would you see my update for the use of `\(sub)import`. Thanks

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there an alternative solution to the package Morewrites ?

Comment: A subsidiary question. One can see the bad result for the `.lof` file. It puts the title "Chapter1" in a bad place. It doesn't put the title "Chapter 3". It does the same thing for the "Appendix 1", and replace it by "chapter 1"... Any ideas for the causes of that !?

Comment: depends on why you actually need it and the rest of your document. If you can switch to lualatex you wouldn't need it at all (but as you are using bidi it is perhaps not easy). Sometimes one can remove or patch packages which waste write streams without needing them (I did that two years ago for a document which took ages to compile before of morewrites).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Lualatex is very beautiful but I'm afraid that it isn't stable yet for arabic packages. I'll try to migrate out morewrites

Comment: I'm sure that there is something abnormal because the time spent is after all the compilation operations, in the very end of compilation.. I have an arabic version of the book and the message 

`(Main.aux (FrontBook.aux) (Stat-Data.aux) (Stat-Param.aux) (Rand-Calc.aux)
(Proba-Space.aux) (Rand-Var.aux) (Usual-Rand-Var.aux)
(Appendix-Quantiles-Functions.aux) (Appendix-Moments-Inequalities.aux)
(Index.aux) (Glossary-Equations.aux) (Glossary-Authors.aux) (Dictionnaries.aux)
 (Normal-Tables.aux))` 

takes 2 seconds to pass not 2 minutes !

Comment: yes this is due to morewrites: it avoids to use many writes by writing everything in one file and at the end of the compilation splits this up and writes it to files. The first time I run into this problem I killed the compilation because I thought that there is a loop somewhere.

Comment: How are you using `morewrites`?  We see that you have a definition involving `\ttfamily`.  Do you do anything involving `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily`?

Comment: I use `morewrites` for the package `glossaries`. I don't know anything about `\ttfamily`, nor `\rmfamily`, nor `\sffamily`.. I don't know whereas I need these fonts or not !